# C++ reference type must be initialized

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm having a spot of trouble with some reference variables, first off here is my class

Header file

```
#pragma once
#include "ImageLoader.h"
#include "FontLoader.h"

class LevelState
{
public:
    LevelState()
private:
    ImageLoader& _imageLoader;
    FontLoader& _fontLoader;
}
```

Class file

```
#include "LevelState.h"

LevelState::LevelState()
{

}
```

now when I go to build I get these errors

```
Error   2   error C2758: 'LevelState::_fontLoader' : a member of reference type must be initialized 
Error   1   error C2758: 'LevelState::_imageLoader' : a member of reference type must be initialized
```

So I then went ahead and updated my constructor to take in a ImageLoader and FontLoader like so

```
LevelState::LevelState(FontLoader& fontLoader, ImageLoader& imageLoader)
{
    _fontLoader = fontLoader;
    _imageLoader = imageLoader;
}
```

But I still get the same error as above, what is going wrong? I know I can change my references to pointers and just assign them that way, but I would prefer to use references as these are safer.

Comment: You must initialize member reference in the constructor initialization list, not in the constructor body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the constructor the following way

```
LevelState::LevelState(FontLoader& fontLoader, ImageLoader& imageLoader)
   :  _fontLoader( fontLoader ), _imageLoader( imageLoader )

{
}
```

In your constructor

```
LevelState::LevelState(FontLoader& fontLoader, ImageLoader& imageLoader)
{
    _fontLoader = fontLoader;
    _imageLoader = imageLoader;
}
```

references are not initialized. There are used assignment statements that try to assign values to objects that have to be referenced to by the references.

This record

```
_fontLoader( fontLoader ), _imageLoader( imageLoader )
```

is called mem-initializer list. It is used to initialize objects (including constants and references)

Take into account that the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator are defined as deleted by the compiler implicitly.

Comment: Awesome that works great, however could you explain why I need to use the : at the end of the method?

Comment: @Canvas As i wrote it is special record of setting initializers for data members of the class.